# My console is not outputting any information?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have just a basic key/click logger for tkinter and I'm trying to display the log as a list to be printed out to the console however it doesn't seem to working at all. I used my terminal by compiling and writing "python logger.py" to try and get it to run and it runs but it prints nothing in the terminal. Then I copied and pasted my code towards PyCharm and it still doesn't seem to output it through the console there.

I pasted my code and was hoping if someone has any ideas on what could be wrong.

```
import tkinter as tkr
Log = []

master = tkr.Tk()

def char(event):
   print("pressed", repr(event.char))
   key1 = repr(event.char)
   Log.append(key1)
   print(Log)

def click(event):
   frame.focus_set()
   print("clicked", event.x,event.y)
   key2 = event.x,event.y
   Log.append(key2)
   print(Log)

frame = tkr.Frame(master, height = 1000, width = 1000)
frame.bind("<Key>",char)
frame.bind("Button-1>",click)
frame.bind("Button-2>",click)
frame.bind("Button-3>",click)
frame.pack()

master.mainloop()
print(Log)
```

Comment: I think you might need to request focus since the frame does not have focus by default. Try using `frame.focus_set()` and see if that changes something?

Comment: One problem here is a typo. You are missing `<` from your binds.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You have typo in `"Button-1>"`, `"Button-2>"`, `"Button-3>"`.

You forgot `<` .

It has to be `"<Button-1>"`, `"<Button-2>"`, `"<Button-3>"`

---

**EDIT:** as said @razdi you need `frame.focus_set()` to get pressed key

```
frame.pack()
frame.focus_set()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!